# RegexExpression for numeric first digit zero is not taken

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have validate AdmissionFee in JavaScript

For validation am using below expression:

```
/^[0-9]+$/
```

When am entering `0 digit only`, its not working. But when entering 1 0r remaining digits up to 9 digits it's working.

Here am not using length also, even its not working.

please give me any suggetion to me.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Do you want it to reject "0", or "00", or "001"? Should it accept the empty string ""?

Comment: Do you have another test too?, e.g. required field, since `if(field.value)` will return false if the field's value is "0".

Comment: What validation code are you using?  Are you using a framework?  The regex is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression looks fine to me. But if you want it to match only numbers starting with a nonzero digit, use

```
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/
```

If you want it to accept 0 as well, you can use

```
/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/
```

If the empty string and 0 are both OK, use

```
/^(0?|[1-9][0-9]*)$/
```

Comment: He says "0" is not being accepted, but according to his regular expression, 0 is allowed.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: I wasn't sure what the OP meant -- perhaps his meaning was that 0 should have been rejected but was not. Hopefully clarification will be forthcoming.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: Exactly.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski what u r saying exactly right.@Charles i tried whatever expressions u r given,but its not working my requirement is i want to allow first digit 0 .But its working for 1 or remaining digits up to 9.Please give me any idea why my expression is not working for 0.

Comment: @user2996174: Your regular expression already accepts numbers starting with 0. The problem is elsewhere in your code.